# LNK1104 error when creating 64bit executable with glut,VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, glut

I have so far managed to create with Visual Studio 2008 a 32-bit executable of an OpenGL C code (last code in http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter01.html) that uses glut (I work in Windows 7 64 bits).

I installed glut files as follows:

glut.h          in    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\gl
glut32.lib    in    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib
glut32.dll    in    C:\Windows\System32

and I have used the command line instruction cl:
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
cl example-opengl.cpp

So far, so good...

I am now trying to create a 64-bit executable.

Based on what I found on the Internet, I tried two installations:

glut.h          in    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v5.0\Include\GL
glut32.lib    in    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v5.0\Lib\
glut32.dll    in    C:\Windows\SysWOW64

and also:

glut.h          in    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\GL
glut32.lib    in    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib
glut32.dll    in    C:\Windows\SysWOW64

and I try to compile with:
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat"
cl example-opengl.cpp

For both installations, there is an error from the linker:
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.lib'

What is the way to fix this before I tear off all my hair?...   ;-)

Notice that I am using only a shell, not the IDE of Visual Studio.

Many thanks in advance for your help.
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have managed to create a 64bit executable with glut by using freeglut
(from site http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/ )

It's good when it's over...   ;-)